# Mapping all subdomains of a domain to an IP

Tags: ip, configuration, hosts

How should I set up a server to map all subdomains of a domain to an IP?

I wish I could do something like that in the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 *.example.com
```

Comment: Not in hosts but in your DNS server.

Comment: All **subdomains** of parent domain or **hosts** unside domain? They are very different things

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mailq mentioned, DNS supports wildcard host entries (while the hosts file does not).

A DNS record with the name `*` will match all names *for which there is no other record on that name*, returning the wildcard record.

An entry would look like this:

```
*    IN    A    192.0.2.1
```

But, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that pointing to 127.0.0.1 - can you clarify what you're attempting to accomplish with this, and we might be able to point you in a better direction?

Comment: CNAME works for hosts, not subdomains as OP asked

Comment: @LazyBadger Huh?  Who said anything about a `CNAME`?

Comment: mea culpa, think and write in parallel. Wildcard RR haven't relation to CNAME, shure